# Transformaciones EPSG en Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, html5, openlayers, leaflet

Estoy migrando de la librería **OpenLayers** a **Leaflet** y tengo este problema:

El código OpenLayers transforma las coordenadas EPSG:4326 a EPSG:3857:

```
var arCoordinates = ol.proj.transform(iarClickCoordinates, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

> **Cómo puede hacerlo en Leaflet?**

Uso Leaflet 1.3.0

Lo busqué en google pero no encontré mucha información.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Noguera. Gracias por traducirla. Has probado algo tras estar investigando por google? Sobre ese intento si nos muestras errores o problemas concretos podemos ayudarte a mejorarlo. Mira [ask] para más info.  Un saludo

Comment: Lo más sencillo sería usar proj4js https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Precisamente encontré el pluguin proj4leaflet para usar diferentes transformaciones, sin embargo no encontré un método para hacer lo mismo que OpenLayers hacía: transformar de EPSG:4326 a EPSG:3857